# Android setOnKeyListener causing ANR (Application Not Responding) prompt

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, onkeydown, android-anr-dialog

I made a simple app that goes through all lines of a large (1.5MB) text file and displays each line that contains a specific word (the word is received from the user via an EditText).
The app definitely puts my device under a lot of strain while it's searching through the text file but I had never received a single ANR prompt *until* I added the code below. Now I receive the ANR prompts often. Removing the code from the app gets rid of the ANR prompts. What is it about this code that could be causing the prompts? Is it written incorrectly? Aside from causing the ANR prompts, it's working properly.

```
editText1.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() 
{
   public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
   {
      if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
      {
      button1.performClick();
      return true;
      }
   return false;
   }
});
```

EDIT:

It appears the ANR prompt was a result of the OnKeyListener process not being able to complete within a few seconds of being triggered via an Enter key press. It wasn't able to complete because it launched a time-consuming resource-hogging process that delayed its completion.
The solution was to just have the OnKeyListener process change the value of a variable, instead of launching the resource-hogging process. This allows the OnKeyListener process to complete right away, then the resource-hogging process is launched from elsewhere (triggered by change in the variable's value).

Below, is the code I'm now using. At a later date, I'll try making a second app that puts the resource-hogging process in the background as recommended by Simon André Forsberg below.

```
   final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
   new Thread(new Runnable()
   {
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      while (true) 
      {
         try 
         {
         mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
         @Override
            public void run()
            {
               if (NeedToClickButton == 1)
               {
               NeedToClickButton = 0
               button1.performClick();
               }
            }   
         });
      } catch (Exception e) {
   }}}}).start();



editText1.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() 
{
   public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
   {
      if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
      {
      NeedToClickButton = 1;
      return true;
      }
   return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Just a side note, according to the java naming conventions, variable names (such as `MyEditText` and `MyButton`) should start with a lowercase letter. Right now, to most java developers on the first look of your code MyEditText and MyButton sounds like a class name considering the uppercase starting letter.

Comment: I believe the call of setOnKeyListener is not what is causing your application to stop responding, but rather what you are actually doing in the click of "MyButton". However, if you believe that the code in your question is what is causing the problem I think you should check how often it is called (add `Log.i("Calling perform click");` before the line "MyButton.performClick();")

Comment: @Simon André Forsberg I'll edit it real quick to prevent confusion.

Comment: @Simon André Forsberg: It shouldn't be clicking the button unless I press the Enter key (unless it's written incorrectly of course) ... I'll try to figure out how to do the Log.i thing you recommended.

Comment: using Log.i is just one way of providing info/debug to the log. To view the log you have to see the logcat, it can be viewed directly within Eclipse or it can also be used by using the adb command. See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Answer (score 1):

You should be performing such long operations in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Here's an example of how I would have done it:

```
class ScanTextTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {
     protected List<String> doInBackground(String... param) {
         // load file from the string param[0]
         // add all the results to a list and return the list
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
         // add the result to the UI of your choice
     }
 }
```

And then, to start the task you use:
`new ScanTextTask().execute(filename);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll be sure to try that next time. For now I just need to figure out how having this OnKeyListener code sitting in my app is causing ANR prompts.

Comment: @EricGlass what happens if you click the button directly, without using the down key method? Does not the ANR happen then as well? I believe switching to an AsyncTask will solve the ANR prompt, as it will perform the operation in the background without blocking the UI-thread.

Comment: Clicking the button (manually or via the Enter key press) does not cause the ANR prompt. The prompt just appears after the app has been searching through the text file for about 4 seconds. If I remove this OnKeyListener code, I get no ANR prompts, even if the app sits there searching for 20 seconds. I will definitely be trying the AsyncTask option in the near future but I've still got to know how adding this bit of of seemingly harmless code is managing to cause ANR prompts to appear when they didn't appear at all before.

Comment: @EricGlass A non-responsive app for 20 seconds is still a problem, even if you don't get an ANR prompt. I believe the reason could be that your code is wanting to be executed twice when you use the key listener, but the second time cannot be executed because the first one is not finished and therefore an ANR prompt appears because your app is simply too busy to respond to code wanting to be executed. You should really use AsyncTasks as soon as possible. It will solve all your problems for now.

Comment: Scratch that. I misread what you said. Pressing the Enter key instead of pressing the on-screen button manually does appear to be what starts the problem. Glad you asked that question. Now we're getting somewhere.

Comment: @EricGlass Getting the app to respond is more important than to get rid of an ANR prompt. I'd say the problem is that you're app is freezing for 20 seconds while it is executing code, not that you get an ANR prompt. The executing of code for 20 seconds on the UI thread is what is causing the ANR prompt, not that you use an OnKeyListener.

Comment: I'll be sure to use that AsyncTasks option in the near future. For now I've just got to know why clicking the button via this bit of setOnKeyListener code is causing an ANR prompt to appear when clicking the on-screen button manually does not. As a side note: 20 seconds was just an example ... the length of the delay is determined by the number (and length) of the lines in the text document ... to get a 20 second delay, it has to be searching all the way through a 3.5MB text file.

Comment: @EricGlass I really think that you are focusing on the wrong thing, but I believe I have made my point already and helped you all that I can and therefore I will shut up and let you continue coding :)

Comment: Hehe, aren't you curious though? I'm too curious to give up when I find something like this. Clicking the button via this OnKeyListener leads to an ANR prompt while pressing the on-screen button manually does not. I find that very interesting.

Comment: In case you're still interested, I just tried something else. I removed the button1.performClick() line. With that line removed, I pressed the on-screen button manually, immediately followed by the Enter key and the ANR prompt appeared 4 seconds later. So it's not the button1.performClick() that's causing it.